# How to add views count for each playlist track?

Tags: php, playlist

I want to add views count inside playlist to show views-count on each track
like this sample:
[image]

Comment: What are you using to even have a playlist? What's your code?

Comment: view on track? you mean listens?

Comment: Yes I want number of listens for each track(audio) in playlist, I am using default wordpress playlist